Run server-side task for specific duration
I'm running a Flask app on a Google Cloud Run service. When a user sends a request to route /api/start_task, a block of code starts running, which can take a very long time to run. For several reasons, I prefer this code to run for a limited amount of time (and the rest will be done later).
What I've done until now is simply set the request timeout parameter for the Cloud Run service. When it reaches the timeout it returns a 504 error (as expected).
I'm looking for a more "elegant" way to do this. Ideally I could define the function to run for X seconds (this doesn't have to be accurate), and then stop and return a successful response (instead of 504).
I thought of simply using something like while (time.time() - start_time) < max_time, and executing the code inside this while block. But I don't know if this is a good idea, or if there's a more efficient way...
